# SharePoint 2010 - Combine existing web parts

Tags: sharepoint, customization, wiki

I love the simplicity of SP Wiki. I have further enhanced the wiki page by adding an additional column/field to categorize each page. I then embedded:
 - a CEWP to include SCRIPTS and STYLES,
 - a list to create a heirarchy (breadcrumb navigation)
 - a document library to highlight resources applicable to that page.

The dynamic effect is acheived by:
1. setting my resource doocuments and breadcrumb list to that exact category and 
2. filtering the list/library web parts via 'connections'.

Whilst it was easy to this set up on 2 or 3 wiki pages, it is time consuming and would be confusing for the person to whom I would soon be handing over this function to create and manage hundreds of pages.

Is there a way to combine all the 3 web parts (and their customization) and export it as a single web part? Or any other way to achieve this?

Note: Unfortunately I am a front end user only - I dont have access to the backend admin access or SP Designer.

Comment: You might get more/better responses on the dedicated [SharePoint StackExchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Save the site as a template :)

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938033(v=office.15).aspx

You create one template wiki, save it as a template including content and you can then create a new site, based on that template.